# Terraria iOS--NPC's not going to their houses?

Tags: terraria

I can't get NPC's to go into their houses in Terraria.  I saw for the PC version that you can just quit out of the game and when you come in they'll be there; this is not the case for iOS.  Could it be that my house is multi-storied (see attached screenshot)?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried walking away during the night? They teleport to their house if you do that on PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a staircase or a lower platform and the NPC should move into his house. This is because the NPC's in the game don't jump as high as you. Good Luck!

Comment: This isn't working.  I placed a platform elevator under the floor and the npc didn't do anything.  Do i just need to make stairs?

Comment: yes make stairs that what I just did and it worked for me